# Anything Slider is stacking list items

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, anythingslider

I am trying to incorporate the AnythingSlider into a RoR site https://amillet89.heroku.com/ and am having trouble getting the slider to work. Instead, the list images are just getting stacked on top of one another. I put an alert statement in the anythingSlider method, which isn't getting called it seems. I checked the resources in Chrome, and it looks like both jQuery and the anythingSlider function are getting loaded (through the asset pipeline in application.js), so I am not sure why it isn't getting called.

```
<div>
  <ul id="slider">
  <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placebear.com/300/200" alt="" /></li>
 <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff.jpg" alt="" /></li>
 <li><img src="http://placedog.com/300/200" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook your js function into `jQuery.ready()` or `jQuery(window).load()` as a callback.

The reason it is not working, is your call to `$('#slider').anythingSlider()` is placed above `<ul id="slider">` and it is executed immediately. When the JS runs, the `#slider` doesn't exist, so the function doesn't do anything. This code should work, but I didn't test.

```
var slider = {
      init: function() {
          $('#slider').anythingSlider({});
     }
}

$(window).load( slider.init )
```

Comment: thanks luke! I'm new to javascript/jQuery, so the explanation in addition to working code helps a lot!